# 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<em id="ProductPrice" class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">$75.00</em>
```

And I need to make the color of the text change color if there is a change to it's value.

I wrote this:

```
<script>

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){

    var currentPrice = $.trim($("#ProductPrice").text());

    if(currentPrice == "%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%") 
    {
            $("#ProductPrice").style.color="black";
            console.log("black");
    }
    else
    {
            $("#ProductPrice").style.color="red";
            console.log("red");
    }

});
```

%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%% is a variable in our CMS that gives the base value before any change occurs.

I get the error 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '&("#ProductPrice").style.color="red"')

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using jQuery selectors in plain Javascript, won't work. In javascript you can change the property `style`, in jQuery you have a method [**.css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to do this.

Try this instead:

```
$("#ProductPrice").css('color','black');
```

or plain javascript

```
document.getElementById('ProductPrice').style.color="black";
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery objects don't have a property called `style`. You're mixing jQuery and native js. Try this:

```
$("#ProductPrice").css('color', 'black');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector)
```

gives you a jQuery object, not the HTMLElement you would try the .style invoke on.

Try this instead:

```
 $("#ProductPrice").css("color", "red");
```